# How to assert the regular expression against my output using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my regex:

```
/(\u20AC|\u00A3)[\d,]*/?(week|wk|month|mth|year|yr)?/
```

How can I verify this regular expression against my output using Selenium?

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Don't use the JavaScript tag then.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider that your selenium output is a variable named "seleniumOut".

The assert in a test with regex can be writted this way:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\u20AC|\u00A3)[\d,]*/?(week|wk|month|mth|year|yr)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(seleniumOut);

assertTrue("regex needs match the selenium output", m.matches());
```

Comment: thank u very much. I have tried using it. But it shows up error saying invalid sequence.

Comment: So your regex is invalid inside a Java context. Regex can change a little if it works in php, lavascript or other language and you are trying to run inside a java code. You need to change and test it before apply inside your selenium test. You can do it with a unit test.